# pandas how to compare rows of 2 dataframes regardless of order

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3,4])


df1['A'] = [1,2,5,4]
df1['B'] = [5,6,9,8]
df1['C'] = [9,10,1,12]

>>> df1
   A  B   C
1  1  5   9
2  2  6  10
3  5  9   1
4  4  8  12
```

I want to compare rows of df1 and get a result of row1(1,5,9) == row3(5,9,1).

It means I care only contained items of row and ignore order of items of row.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @jezrael I didn't think about output, but the purpose is to find/remove duplicated rows.

Comment: OK, give me as ec for edit answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need sorting each row by [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df1.values, axis=1), index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
print (df2)
   A  B   C
1  1  5   9
2  2  6  10
3  1  5   9
4  4  8  12
```

And then remove duplicates by inverted `(~)` boolean mask created by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df1.values, axis=1), index=df1.index)
print (df2)
   0  1   2
1  1  5   9
2  2  6  10
3  1  5   9
4  4  8  12

df1 = df1[~df2.duplicated()]
print (df1)
   A  B   C
1  1  5   9
2  2  6  10
4  4  8  12
```

Comment: OP is also asking about row comparisons, not just sorting it.

Comment: @iDrwish - Yes, this should be first step, I also ask OP in comment for expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If no value is present twice in a columnm you could just simply translate your columnns into a `set`

```
row1 = df.iloc[1]
row3 = df.iloc[3] 
set(row1) == set(row3)
```

it has the advantage that you can then compare your columns, e.g to find if there is a value in one and not the other.

```
row1 - row3 # find the values that are in row1 but not in row3
```